# Redirect based on query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to update the `.htaccess` file to redirect web users from pages on older version of our site to our current site.

The old PHP files have no direct relationship to file names and extensions used on our current site.

For example:

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/site/properties/properties.php?id=Smith
```

To:

```
http://mydomain.com/properties/sally-smith/
```

Or:

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/site/properties/properties.php?id=Jones
```

To:

```
http://mydomain.com/properties/robert-jones/
```

My site has several more pages with same path but with different PHP `id`'s. I am getting stumped on how to handle each individual `id` in writing a 301 redirect from old pages to their corresponding current pages.

Comment: It appears the `ID` only contains the last name. How do you plan to handle its redirect and include the first name? Otherwise you will most likely have to rewrite each url and if your site is large, that is not practical.

Comment: Like Panama said, what you can do is redirect `properties.php?id=Smith` into `/properties/smith/` but not with the first name as you don't have any reference of the first name on the previous URL. How do you know the ID smith is not John Smith but Sally Smith if that is even possible on your system is another question? What you could try to do is redirect all the URL to a PHP page that would verify the link and by itself redirect again to the proper place.